# AttributeError vs code

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am new to python and using vs code. I am trying to make a flappy bird game but I am experiencing an error: AttributeError: 'Bird' object has no attribute 'move'. I have marked the line where the error takes place. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

```
import pygame
import time
import os
import random
import neat

WIN_WIDTH = 600
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("bird1.png"))),    pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("bird2.png"))),  pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG =  [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("pipe.png")))]
BASE_IMG =  [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("base.png")))]
BG_IMG =  [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("bg.png")))]

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0

        def jump(self):
            self.vel = -10.5
            self.tick_count = 0
    
        def move(self):
            self.tick_count += 1

            d = self.vel*self.tick_count+1.5*self.tick_count**2
        
            if d >= 16:
              d = 16

            if d < 0:
                d = -2

            self.y = self.y + d

            if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
                if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                    self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
            else:
                if self.tilt > -90:
                    self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0
    
        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)))
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 350)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
         for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
        **bird.move()** <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Error here
        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

I was expecting to work as I did everything the tutorial told me to in the exact way.

Comment: `def jump` and `def move` are indented one level too far. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. ["Can someone help me?" is not considered an actual question on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the indentations of the functions `jump` and `move` inside the `Bird` class.
They are indented as if they are defined in `__init__`, so the other class method can not see them.

Indent them at the level of `__init__` (instead of inside of `__init__`) as they will become visible and the error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your putting the function `bird.move()` inside `__init__`. To fix your error you need to move the functions inside `__init__` to inside the Bird class. Having functions that use the `self._` don't need to be in the `__init__` function. Change the indentations to move the code to directly inside the Bird class